# Swap two nibbles in a byte

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am trying to swap two nibbles in a byte on my own. The solution on the Internet seem obvious which is

```
( (x & 0x0F)<<4 | (x & 0xF0)>>4 )
```

I know how the above solution works. I tried on my own which looks something like this

```
(((0x0F<<4)&(n)) | (0x0F & (n>>4)))
```

In the first operation : I am trying to shift `1111` 4 places to the left and then `&` with `n` to get the first four bits.

In the second operation: I am trying to shift `n` 4 place to the right and then `&` with `1111` to get the last four bits.

And then `OR` to give the final answer.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: You could simplify `0x0F<<4` to just `0xF0`.

Comment: Thank you!!! Didn't know that

Comment: Did you try it ? Is it working ? What is your question, exactly ?

Comment: It is not working.Yes,I tried it

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've tried it, so you know there's some inputs for which it doesn't get the right answer (for example: 0x01). Where are you stuck debugging why the method doesn't work for these numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a number in binary:

```
abcdwxyz
```

When using `( (x & 0x0F)<<4 | (x & 0xF0)>>4 )`:

`(x & 0x0F)<<4` gives `wxyz0000`

`(x & 0xF0)>>4` gives `0000abcd`

so the final answer is `wxyzabcd`.

When using `(((0x0F<<4)&(n)) | (0x0F & (n>>4)))` instead, `(0x0F<<4)` is the same as `0xF0`, so:

`(0xF0 & (n))` gives `abcd0000`

`(0x0F & (n>>4))` gives `0000abcd`

so the final answer is `abcdabcd`.

Instead you could try:

```
((0xF0 & (n<<4)) | (0x0F & (n>>4)))
```